# replace variables with structs queriing with golang

Tags: go

I've this snippet of code that works:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "pwd@tcp(ip:port)/db")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
rows, err := db.Query("select username from users")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
var (
    username string
)
for rows.Next() {
    err = rows.Scan(
        &name,
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(username)
}
```

But, ... is it possible to substitute

```
var (
    username string
)
```

and 
    err = rows.Scan(
        &name,
    )

with a struct?

I ask this because every time I want to add new field I need to

- add field inside the query
- create new variable in "var" block
- add variable to scan

May I define a struct and update fields in just one place? Or, ... are there some best practice to build queries and fetch them?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&username` in the `rows.Scan()`?

Comment: I submitted an edit for that. Turns out I made 2k rep today so I could directly edit it now, but that effectively bumps it in the lists, so it wouldn't be productive.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
type user struct {
    Name  string
    Pass  string
    Email string
    Age   int
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "pwd@tcp(ip:port)/db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    rows, err := db.Query("select user, pass, email, age from users")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    var (
        users []user
    )
    for rows.Next() {
        u := user{}
        err = rows.Scan(
            &u.Name, &u.Pass, &u.Email, &u.Age,
        )
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        users = append(users, u)
    }
    fmt.Println(users)
}
```

Comment: Yet, it is better. But instead of just declare each variables for each fields you just suggest to create a struct. Is this the common way you use each time you scan rows?

Comment: Yes I think so. You could try to generalise using reflect but then you kind of go around the type system of go -- making it slower and prone to errors.

Comment: You can also have a look at [gorm](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/). I have not used it but it seems to pup up everywhere. That way you avoid doing the database layer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a library, https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx is perfect for the job.

```
place := Place{}
rows, err := db.Queryx("SELECT * FROM place")
for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.StructScan(&place)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    } 
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", place)
}
```

There is some basic usage in the github readme https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx as well as some "standard" documentation the maintainer has written http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/ and finally, the godoc http://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx

One thing to note, is that `sqlx` made the design choice similar to the way the go compiler forces you to use variables that you have created. So if you select a column that isn't in your struct, it throws an error. The reasons for this are sound and promote good `sql` practices. `Select *` when you only need one column is crazy expensive. See his notes here http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#safety